# Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar in wxPython Panel

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

I am working on a GUI (developed with wxPython) where you can plot graphs on different panels. At the moment I have this:

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,'Plot',size=(1000,800))

        # Main Panel (It will contain other elements besides the plotting panel)
        self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1,size=(1000,800))
        self.mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour('gray')

        # Plotting panel
        self.plottingPanel = wx.Panel(self,-1,pos=(50,20),size=(500,400))
        self.plottingPanel.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        # Plot example
        figure = plt.figure()
        axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01); s = np.cos(2 * np.pi * t);axes.plot(t,s)
        plt.title('Cosine')
        plt.xlabel('x');plt.ylabel('y')

        # Canvas
        canvas = FigureCanvas(self.plottingPanel,-1,figure)
        # Navegation toolbar
        navToolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(canvas)
        navToolbar.DeleteToolByPos(6);navToolbar.DeleteToolByPos(2);navToolbar.DeleteToolByPos(1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(canvas)
        sizer.Add(navToolbar)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Frame = Frame()
        self.Frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.Frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the script get this:

[image]

I have colored the plotting panel white to highlight it. How can the plot size be adapted to the panel size?

I want to get something like this (this is a montage):

[image]

On the other hand, I managed to eliminate from the bar some buttons that are unnecessary for what I need but the bar does not work, that is, when pressing the buttons nothing happens :(

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set parameters when the container for the plot elements ([`matplotlib.figure.Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure)) is created.
e.g. `figsize` sets the figure dimension in inches and `tight_layout` adjust the sub plots in tight layout.

```py
figure = plt.figure(figsize = (4, 3), tight_layout=True)
```

---

Alternatively you can set the position of the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html) object by [`.set_position`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position):

```py
figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.set_position(pos = [0.15,0.3,0.55,0.55], which='both')
```

[image]